# Accessing some files/folders in SVN Server running on Windows 7

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I am new to SVN and have installed VisualSVN Server on a Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit OS. I have the server setup to use SSL on port `443`. My router uses a virtual server entry to direct incoming requests to the SVN server machine  by sending incoming requests on port `8443` to `192.168.2.100:443`. I have my clients (TortiseSVN 32bit) installed on windows XP SP2 machines.

Generally everything appears to work. I can access the repository from both clients via a browser using the defined url except that the servername is being replaced with a local network ip. In this case `https://192.168.2.100:8443`. I can also access the repository from TortiseSVN Repo Browser.

My basic repository structure is

```
  svn/
    PLATFORM_FOLDER/
     Project/
       branch/
       tag/
       trunk/
```

I Import a project by navigating to the root folder of the project on the client, then using the TortiseSVN>>Import menu item to upload the project files/folders to the project/trunk folder in SVN. No errors when uploading. FYI: In this case the project is and Android app developed using eclipse.

When I browse the repository via the clients web browser all is ok. But when I view the project from the TortiseSVN Repo Browser, 2 of the Imported folders give me errors:

```
PROPFIND of 'sn/!svn/bc/47/PROJECT/trunk/src/com/appname:Could not read response body: SSL error: wrong version number (https://192.168.2.100:8443).
```

One of the folders contains xml text files, and the other folder contains java code files and one folder with additional java files.

Other folders which have binary image files and xml files can be viewed ok.

I can't figure out why only certain folders have a problem. If it were an SSL issue, wouldn't it happen to all folders??

Some of my filenames contain underscore characters. Is this not allowed?, or are there any specific file format issues I should be aware of?

Comment: which version of tortoise SVN do you use? And which version is installed in the server?

Comment: TortoiseSVN 1.6.12, Build 20536 - 32 Bit , 2010/11/24 20:59:01 / 
Subversion 1.6.15, / 
apr 1.3.8 / 
apr-utils 1.3.9 / 
neon 0.29.5 / 
OpenSSL 0.9.8p 16 Nov 2010 / 
zlib 1.2.3 /

Comment: VisualSVN Server version 2.1.5

Comment: This post should not be tagged for Android

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking out your code on the server itself? The problem may be in the router, it can process propfind requests differently.

Comment: if by checkingout you mean accessing the repository via TortoiseSVN installed on the server. Yes. Tried both 32 &  64bit versions. Same 2 folders give same error. I have not however tried importing the files using TortoiseSVN from the server. I will try that and let you know.

Comment: I placed a copy of the files on the server. I then used TortoiseSVN 64bit (on the server) to Import to the trunk as explained above. The same problem occurs. My thought is this totsally rules out any SSL problem??

Answer (score 1):

I was getting essentially the same error:

> PROPFIND of 'sn/!svn/bc/47/PROJECT/trunk/src/com/appname:Could not
>   read response body: SSL error: wrong version number
>   (https://192.168.2.100:8443).

(except my error shows paths for my repo and server name).

In my case, this issue ocurred for a remote user who had two computers on his home LAN -- each one connected to the office via a FortiClient SSL VPN connection.  One of his computers could reliably access Subversion, while the other computer got the above Subversion errors during CHECKOUT or REPO BROWSER activity.

The IP address subnet in the main office is **192.168.1.###**, and the IP address subnet at the remote office LAN was **192.168.2.###**.  But in the main office, the FortiGate 80C was configured to assign incomming SSL VPN client connections to IP addresses within the **192.168.2.###** subnet -- which is the same subnet as configured at the remote location.

So, I changed the FortiGate 80C to assign VPN users to an address in the **192.168.3.###** subnet, and voila -- both computers in the remote location can now access Subversion reliably and simultaneously.  The "Response Body - SSL Error - Wrong Version" errors are gone. Below are the relavent network settings, for reference:

---

### MAIN OFFICE

```
Primary subnet:  192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
FortiGate IP:    192.168.1.1
FortiGate address object:
   Name:                        SSLVPN_TUNNEL_ADDR1
   IP range:                    192.168.3[100-150]   
                                (This is the subnet for VPN clients.
                                 Previously was 192.168.2[100-150], which conflicted
                                 with the 192.168.2 subnet at the remote location)
FortiGate static route:
   Destination IP:              192.168.3.0/255.255.255.0
   Device:                      ssl.root
                                (allows VPN clients to access servers
                                 within the main office)
FortiGate Policy:
   Source Interface/Zone:       sslvpn tunnel interface
   Source Address:              SSLVPN_TUNNEL_ADDR1
   Destination Interface/Zone:  internal
   Destination Address:         all
   Schedule:                    always
   Service:                     ANY
   Action:                      ACCEPT
                                (allows VPN clients to access servers
                                 within the main office)
```

### REMOTE HOME OFFICE

```
Primary subnet:      192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0
Belkin Router IP:    192.168.2.1
```